# Query parameter handling in karate framework

Tags: karate

Is there any easy way to handle huge query param like below. Also I would like to know how can I do run time parameterisation for some values?

http://154.213.196.243:7941/v1/banking/Jumio/callback?callBackType=NetVerifyId&jumioIdScanReference=123abcde-1244-8571-3454-abcd12345567&merchantIdScanReference=66a9ff2e-d8ec-e811-a956-000d3ab3f117&verificationStatus=APPROVED_VERIFIED&idScanStatus=SUCCESS&id+ScanSource=API&idCheckDataPositions=OK&idCheckDocumentValidation=OK&idCheckHologram=OK&idCheckMRZcode=OK&idCheckMicroprint=OK&idCheckSecurityFeatures=OK&idCheckSignature=OK&transactionDate=2018-11-20T20%3A53%3A25.797Z&callbackDate=2018-11-20T20%3A53%3A25.797Z&idType=DRIVING_LICENSE&idCountry=GBR&idScanImage+=https%3A%2F%2Fnetverify.com%2Frecognition%2Fv1%2Fidscan%2F123abcde-1244-8571-3454-abcd12345567%2Ffront&idFirstName=ILARIA&idLastName=FURS&idDob=1976-12-23&idExpiry=2025-12-31&personalNumber=123456789&clientIp=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&idAddress=%7B%22country%22%3A%22USA%22%2C%20%22stateCode%22%3A%22US-OH%22%7D&idNumber=P12345&idStatus=TESTER961260SS9DL54&identityVerification=%7B%22similarity%22%3A%22MATCH%22%2C%22validity%22%3Atrue%7D HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#param

For example:

```
* param callBackType = 'NetVerifyId'
```

and so on. And look at `params` where you can set all keys up as one single JSON and also do parameterization if needed, there are multiple possibilities: https://github.com/intuit/karate#params

See this example as well: [`dynamic-params.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :) @Peter Thomas